# Keep impromptu "up" while performing a jquery Ajax/MVC post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, impromptu

Is there a way to keep the impromptu dialog box displayed during a post?
Here's the javascript code

```
$('#linkPostTest').click(function() {        
      openprompt();
});

function openprompt() {
    var temp = {
        state0: {
            html: 'Are you sure you want to post?<br />',
            buttons: { Yes: true, No: false },
            focus: 1,
            submit: function(v, m, f) {
                if (v) {
                    var form = $('frmPostTest');
                    $.ajax(
                            {
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '/Path/TestPost',
                                data: form.serialize(),
                                success: function(data) {
                                            // I realize I could check "data" 
                                            // for true...just have not 
                                            // implemented that yet....
                                    $.prompt.goToState('state1');
                                    //$.prompt('Test was successful!');
                                },
                                error: function() {
                                    $.prompt.goToState('state2');
                                    //$.prompt('Test was not successful.');
                                }
                            }
                        );

                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    //$.prompt.goToState('state1'); //go forward
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        state1: {
            html: 'Test was successful!',
            buttons: { Close: 0 },
            focus: 0,
            submit: function(v, m, f) {
                if (v === 0) {
                    $.prompt.close();
                }
            }
        },
        state2: {
            html: 'Test was not successful.<br />',
            buttons: { Close: 0 },
            submit: function(v, m, f) {
                if (v === 0) {
                    $.prompt.close();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    $.prompt(temp);
}
```

The controller does this

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public bool TestPost()
    {            
        // runs some code that saves some data...
        // this works fine
        bool updated = functionThatSavesCode();
        return updated;
    }
```

After I click Yes when the 'Are you sure you want to post?' impromptu dialog is displayed... it disappears...How can I make it stay displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK got it to work...I'm really impressed with the impromptu plug-in and jQuery!
Two of the things I did differently to get this to work was to add the two

```
return false;
```

statements under the state0 block and...

to set the the ajax call to

```
async: false,
```

Here's the new javascript:

```
$('#linkTestPost').click(function() {
    TestPost();
});

function TestPost() {
    var temp = {
        state0: {
            html: 'Are you sure you want to post?<br />',
            buttons: { Yes: true, No: false },
            focus: 1,
            submit: function(v, m, f) {
                if (v) {
                    if (PostView() === true) {
                        $.prompt.goToState('state1');
                        // the line below was missing from my original attempt
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $.prompt.goToState('state2');
                        // the line below was missing from my original attempt
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else {                        
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        state1: {
            html: 'Test Post was successful!',
            buttons: { Close: 0 },
            focus: 0,
            submit: function(v, m, f) {
                if (v === 0) {
                    $.prompt.close();
                }
            }
        },
        state2: {
            html: 'Test Post was not successful',
            buttons: { Close: 0 },
            submit: function(v, m, f) {
                if (v === 0) {
                    $.prompt.close();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    $.prompt(temp);
}

function PostView() {
    var form = $('frmTestPost');
    var postSuccess = new Boolean();        
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Path/TestPost',
        data: form.serialize(),
        // the line below was missing from my original attempt
        async: false,            
        success: function(data) {
            postSuccess = true;
        },
        error: function() {
            postSuccess = false;
        }
    });        
    return postSuccess;
}
```