# jquery impromptu - keeping prompt open until asynchronous AJAX reponse is processed

Tags: javascript, jquery, impromptu

**In brief**
I want to do some asynchronous server side validation (using AJAX) after user clicks "Ok" button. If the validation fails, I want to show the error message over the prompt without closing it.

**Details**

I am using impromptu version 3.1. I could not find the documentation of 3.1 so checked in the [documentation for version 4.0.1](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php) that there are two ways to do this -

> Return false or event.preventDefault() to keep the prompt open

I checked that since I am using an older version, the event variable is not available inside function like this -

```
$.prompt('Example 2',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }, submit: submitCertificationPrompt } });

function submitCertificationPrompt(e,v,m,f)
{
 //e is not available in case of version 3.0.1
}
```

I cannot upgrade to the latest version right now, because there are some customizations we did on the version 3.1 plugin code.

So, I am left with using the `return false` way. I checked that this works -

```
 $.prompt('Example 2',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }, submit: submitCertificationPrompt } });

    function submitCertificationPrompt()
    {
       return false;
    }
```

But, since I have to wait until the AJAX response is received, I tried using a javascript callback function like this but it is not working like I expected -

```
$.prompt('Example 2',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }, submit: function(){ submitCertificationPrompt(function(bool){ return bool; }) } });

function submitCertificationPrompt(callback)
{
    //I will do an AJAX call here and the prompt should stay open if the response reads validation error. So, I will callback false in that case

    callback(false);
}
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

you need to make a small change just add one more parameter async: false, where you are calling ajax like below

```
 $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/Path/TestPost',
                            async: false,
                            data: form.serialize(),
                            success: function(data) {
```

}

more info : [Keep impromptu "up" while performing a jquery Ajax/MVC post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277976/keep-impromptu-up-while-performing-a-jquery-ajax-mvc-post)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not quite sure what you're doing but utilize the fact that $.ajax is implementing the [jQuery deferred interface](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
$.ajax({
    // the opts for the call.
    // see the documentation.
}).promise().then(function()
{
    // this gets executed when the ajax call comes back with an OK HTTP code like 200
    // perform console.log(arguments) here to see what you get.
}, function()
{
    // this gets executed when the ajax call comes back with an ERROR HTTP code like 500
    // perform console.log(arguments) here to see what you get.
}).always(function()
{
    // this gets always executed.
    // perform console.log(arguments) here to see what you get.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not sure whether I can actually use a deferred along with event handlers of impromptu. Let me describe what happens in the UI, user clicks somewhere and a prompt appears (impromptu is a jquery plugin for showing customized prompts), with "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons at the bottom. I am talking about this Ok button in my question. Then if user clicks on Ok, I want to make an AJAX call. Meanwhile, I want keep the prompt showing and close it if AJAX response was false.